# How do I view an ics file from a Calender invite mail?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems, actionmailer, icalendar

In my invite.ics file, All i see is the calender object `#<Icalendar::Calendar:0xb299a54>`
I tried implementing this [link](https://github.com/icalendar/icalendar) also but i get the same .ics file with the object. I am new to ruby. Can anyone please refer me a better tutorial on sending calendar invites for google calendar, outlook, ical.
Here's the code so far.

```
class MeetingNotification < ActionMailer::Base
  # include Icalendar
   def meeting_request_with_calendar
     mail(:to => "ashi_12@gmail.com", :subject => "iCalendar",
                  :from => "tester@gmail.com") do |format|
       format.ics {
       ical = Icalendar::Calendar.new
       e = Icalendar::Event.new
       e.start = DateTime.now.utc
       e.start.icalendar_tzid="UTC" # set timezone as "UTC"
       e.end = (DateTime.now + 1.day).utc
       e.end.icalendar_tzid="UTC"
       e.organizer "tester@gmail.com"
       e.uid "MeetingRequest"
       e.summary "Scrum Meeting"
       e.description <<-EOF
         Venue: Office
         Date: 16 August 2013
         Time: 10 am
       EOF
       ical.add_event(e)
       ical.publish
       ical.to_ical
       render :text => ical, :layout => false
      }
    end
  end
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I may be too late to answer..I had the same issue . I fixed it by calling `to_ical` while using render method. Try this

```
render :text => ical.to_ical
```